Using ProxyJump option for SSH tunnel with multiple hops
I need to create a tunnel from localhost to host2 through host1, so I'm using the approach suggested in this answer:

ssh -L 9998:host2:22 -N host1
ssh -L 9999:localhost:1234 -N -p 9998 localhost

This will open a tunnel from localhost to host1 through which the SSH service on host2 can be used. Then a second tunnel is opened from localhost to host2 through the first tunnel.

like this:
ssh -L 10022:host2:22 user1@host1
ssh -p 10022 -L 5678:host2:5678 user2@localhost

Is it possible to use ProxyJump approach here instead?
I could connect to the host2 with the jump like this:
ssh -J user1@host1 user2@host2

Update
Figured out how to do it:
ssh -L 5678:host2:5678 -J user1@host1 user2@host2


If the port 5678 on host2 is accessible from host1 and you don't need ssh connection to host2 and you don't need encryption on forwarded connection simple ssh -L 5678:host2:5678 user1@host1 may just be all you need.

yeah, thanks, but there's a wirefall in between the machines so I decided to use port 22 for the inter-communication which is exposed

"Figured out how to do it" – This belongs to an answer, not to the question.
